# How can I stop apt-get from asking about using minor amounts of additional disk space that will be used?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, apt

I know that I can use parameters (with aliases or `apt.conf` to make it permanent) to skip this step.

But, I still want to be warned about major amounts of used disk space, what seems to be purpose of this function.

The problem is that I and `apt-get` have different opinion in terms of what major amount of disk space is.

- for me it would be over 200MB.

And `apt-get`

- well:

  `After this operation, 9805 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y`

Comment: There is no threshold parameter in `apt-get` you can currently set that accomplishes this, unless you want to contribute to the source yourself. I could write a simple shell script function if need be, that uses this behavior. Why is storage such a concern? Unless you're on an embedded platform, storage is cheap these days.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding -y to apt-get like this

```
 apt-get -y install [packagename]
```

Although this will not distinguish minor from major amount of disk space. I am not sure there if this is a way to achieve it.

Comment: I am aware about this - "I know that I can use parameters (with aliases or apt.conf I can even make it permanent) to skip this steep."

Comment: The answer is useful for others, but does not answer the given question.